# PHP: Write SOAP request containing XML data and SOAPHeader

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

Hi I've got an issue with PHP SOAP request and I'm exhausted of the samples found on the web. Following is the request XML which i need to send.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/ISessionManager/Logon</Action>
<h:ContractVersion xmlns:h="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices">330</h:ContractVersion>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<LogonRequest xmlns="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/ServiceContracts/SessionService">
  <logonRequestData xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Session" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <d4p1:DomainCode>WWW</d4p1:DomainCode>
    <d4p1:AgentName>API****</d4p1:AgentName>
    <d4p1:Password>********</d4p1:Password>
    <d4p1:LocationCode i:nil="true" />
    <d4p1:RoleCode>APIB</d4p1:RoleCode>
    <d4p1:TerminalInfo i:nil="true" />
  </logonRequestData>
</LogonRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The WSDL contains `http://pastie.org/9263788`

I have tried the following code

```
$test = array("DomainCode"=>"WWW","AgentName"=>"API****",
              "Password"=>"******","RoleCode"=>"APIB",
              "LocationCode"=>"","TerminalInfo"=>"");

$wsdl = "https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/sessionmanager.svc?wsdl";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1,'exceptions' => true));

$header = new SoapHeader('http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/ISessionManager/Logon','ContractVersion','330', '1');
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

try {    
$logon_request = $client->Logon($test);
print_r($logon_request);
echo "success!";
} catch (SoapFault $soap_error) {
echo $soap_error;
echo "error!";
}
```

I have generated the functions using `$client->__getFunctions()`

```
 array(4) {
 [0]=>
 string(54) "void ChangePassword(ChangePasswordRequest $parameters)"
 [1]=>
 string(45) "LogonResponse Logon(LogonRequest $parameters)"
 [2]=>
 string(38) "void Logout(LogoutRequest $parameters)"
 [3]=>
 string(75) "TransferSessionResponse TransferSession(TransferSessionRequest $parameters)"
 }
```

And the types are in this link `http://pastie.org/9289906`

The link `https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/SessionManager.svc?xsd=xsd3`  contained in the WSDL has ContractVersion information

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices">
<xs:element name="ContractVersion" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="LogonResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Signature" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Signature" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

CODE UPDATE

```
$wsdl = 'https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/sessionmanager.svc?wsdl';
$header = new SoapHeader('http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices','ContractVersion','330', '1');

$ns_d4p1 = 'http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Session';
$ns_i = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1));
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$logonResquestData = new SimpleXMLElement("<logonRequestData xmlns:i='$ns_i' xmlns:d4p1='$ns_d4p1' />");

$logonResquestData->addChild('d4p1:DomainCode', 'WWW', $ns_d4p1);
$logonResquestData->addChild('d4p1:AgentName', 'APISERANGOONAT', $ns_d4p1);
$logonResquestData->addChild('d4p1:Password', 'Newskies-1', $ns_d4p1);
$logonResquestData->addChild('d4p1:LocationCode', null, $ns_d4p1)->addAttribute('i:nil', 'true', $ns_i);
$logonResquestData->addChild('d4p1:RoleCode', 'APIB', $ns_d4p1);
$logonResquestData->addChild('d4p1:TerminalInfo', null, $ns_d4p1)->addAttribute('i:nil', 'true', $ns_i);

//var_dump($logonResquestData->asXML());

$logon_request = $client->Logon($logonResquestData);

return $logon_request;
```

The above code throws the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] LogonRequest.AgentName:LengthStringAttribute: The value of LogonRequest.AgentName:LengthStringAttribute is empty, but is not optional. in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ezyflying.com\tiger\x.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ezyflying.com\tiger\x.php(22): SoapClient->__call('Logon', Array) #1 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ezyflying.com\tiger\x.php(22): SoapClient->Logon(Object(SimpleXMLElement)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ezyflying.com\tiger\x.php on line 22
```

Comment: I added to the answer information about creating the data you send as a parameter to the soap request. I hope it helps you solve your issues.

Comment: I rolled back the previous question. If you make radical edits that change the question your account may be flagged. If you have a new topic, create a new question addressing it and link to the previous question.

Comment: Since you solved the header issue, I would actually suggest you created a **new** question *focused* on passing the parameters to the soap client. To make it easy for those who will try to answer it, you should include in the question excerpts from the *relevant* code, which is: the WSDL, the Schema definitions for `LogonRequest`, `logonRequestData` and each of the `logonRequestData` child elements. Without that information, you will have a hard time getting a good answer. Write a clear, objective question, with a clear title dealing with *one* problem. Your chances will be higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that the header `ContractVersion` from the namespace you used when declaring the header "was not understood". That's because there is probably no `ContractVersion` element declared in the schema for this target namespace.

According to your SOAP request `ContractVersion` belongs to *another* namespace:

```
<h:ContractVersion xmlns:h="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices">
```

You should use *that* namespace when adding the header:

```
$header = new SoapHeader('http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices','ContractVersion','330', '1');
```

As for your `LogonRequest` data, according to the result you expect to generate you will need to add a `LogonRequestData` object to it. Your schema is not available and I don't know the exact syntax using the PHP API. One way would be to add the payload as *literal XML*. You might have to set some configuration in your SOAP client for this and I'm not sure if this is the standard recommended procedure for PHP. If you can send literal XML, then you can build a `<logonRequestData>` object like the one you posted using the code below:

```
$ns_d4p1 = 'http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Session';
$ns_i = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';

$logonResquestData = new SimpleXMLElement("<logonRequestData xmlns:i='$ns_i' xmlns:d4p1='$ns_d4p1' />");

$logonResquestData->addChild('d4p1:DomainCode', 'WWW', $ns_d4p1);
$logonResquestData->addChild('d4p1:AgentName', 'API****', $ns_d4p1);
$logonResquestData->addChild('d4p1:Password', '****', $ns_d4p1);
$logonResquestData->addChild('d4p1:LocationCode', null, $ns_d4p1)->addAttribute('i:nil', 'true', $ns_i);
$logonResquestData->addChild('d4p1:RoleCode', 'APIB', $ns_d4p1);
$logonResquestData->addChild('d4p1:TerminalInfo', null, $ns_d4p1)->addAttribute('i:nil', 'true', $ns_i);
```

You can check if the code above generates the correct XML by printing:

```
print_r($logonResquestData->asXML());
```

Now you have to add that object to your `LogonRequest` object by passing it as a parameter to your `Logon` operation somehow. I'm not sure about the exact syntax. You might need to add a [SoapParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapparam.soapparam.php) or a [SoapVar](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php#104065). You suggested using an array. Whatever the method, you have to test it and see if it generates the correct XML before attempting to send it. It will be easier to debug that way.

Comment: Hi! Nice to see you again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099302/how-to-write-a-php-soap-request-for-the-xml-with-header-mustunderstand

Comment: Oh, so it's the same problem. Still didn't fix it? It's very hard to know how your request should be formed without seeing your Schema (the `LogonRequest` element).

Comment: I would like to give you access to my server so that you can have a look. I've created so many questions regarding the same issue :( Unfortunately I can't seek help from anybody else. Can you help me out via teamviewer? I know der should be a simple fix bu t got no idea about SOAP or XML

Comment: Open the schema which contains an element declaration for `LoginRequest`. In your previous question you included it for `LoginResponse`, so it shouldn't be hard to find. Or you could place that schema here or in a pastebin. It would be helpful.

Comment: LogonRequest is here http://pastie.org/9290170 in the url https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/SessionManager.svc?xsd=xsd0

Comment: And this link has Logon Response https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/SessionManager.svc?xsd=xsd3 . Response is here http://pastie.org/9290175

Comment: The answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381457/exception-in-my-first-soap-client help me fix ?

Comment: Ok. I think I can simply use the data you posted and generate a XML, since the header issue was already resolved. I will edit the answer soon.

Comment: You should not replace the questions. It invalidates the answers. If an answer solves your problem you should accept it and deal with different topics in a followup question.

Comment: Where is the $header used in the code ? Could you please update your answer with the full code? I'm afraid of getting into this as I would make it more confusing to me.

Comment: The header part is working, is it not? Your problem seems to be configuring the soap body parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test your environment here. I would suggest you try to get a very simple PHP WebService example working first. Not the one you are using now. Once that works, it will be easier for you to understand this other one. It seems that in PHP there are many ways to do the same thing and that can be very confusing. It's also important to be able to print the generated request before sending. A soap request is a XML file. If you send a valid static XML file with a SOAP request to your WebService endpoint, it will work. Use those tools. It will help debug and understand the problem

Comment: Hi, I've continued my question in a new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247793/php-soap-request-xml-body-missing-in-the-request